# Controlling an IP camera with ONVIF

Tags: api, rest, soap, onvif

I am looking to control a camera using ONVIF. I need to be able to query the PTZ values and move to specific PTZ values using API. Essentially I want to be able to send a command like this.

```
Http://{IP Address}/onvif/......
```

then have the command return XML or JSON of the PTZ values so I can validate a move was successful or create a preset of the values in my application. The camera I am using is a Bosch IP camera.

Comment: http://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl/ptz.wsdl - you can do it with post-requests. Requests and responses use XML. You can manage presets, move camera etc.